# WPF Lambda expression "where" - elements of a List

Tags: wpf, lambda

My project contains some (Comboboxes with Checkboxes) binging to the same Observable Collection.

If I checked an Item from the Main Combobox I should filter/update the information from the other combo

```
TmpFilter.Where(m => m.CarID == "MINI").ToList();
```

And there is no problem, but if the user checks more than one option ("MINI", "AUDI" ... ), a list of options. I dont know how to make the query.

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the list of selected items from first combobox -

```
List<string> selectedItems;
```

And can check if item is present in the list using simple query -

```
TmpFilter.Where(m => selectedItems.Contains(m.CarID)).ToList();
```

Comment: Glad to help.. Make sure you accept the answer if it solves your query..!!